# Getting the PageFormat of the default Media from a printer in Java

Tags: java, printing

I'm looking to get the default Media of the default printer to pull out the PageFormat without calling the pageDialog of a PrinterJob. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
PrintService defaultPrintService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
Media res = (Media)defaultPrintService.getDefaultAttributeValue(Media.class);
PrintRequestAttributeSet attr_set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
attr_set.add(res);
PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
PageFormat pageFormat = pj.getPageFormat(attr_set);
```

It does what I need it to do. Unfortunately, it takes a fairly significant amount of time to do the getDefaultAttributeValue function call. I'm guessing it makes a query to the printer itself? Anyways, the main question is if there is a more efficient, less costly way to find the default Media type of a printer.

Comment: I am having more or less this issue myself.

Comment: The printer you are querying is a remote printer?

Comment: Just tested your code and it returns immediately, yours must be a remote printer.